# Insert date in procedure

Tags: plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
CREATE PROCEDURE check(date_in IN date)
IS
v_date date;

BEGIN
v_date:=date_in;
dbms_output.put_line(v_date);
END;
.
run;
```

execute check('2011/06/06'); 
error code-ora-1861 ,literal does not match string format.
In which format should I enter it?

EDIT: I do not want to use to_date

Comment: What is the purpose of this procedure? What is it supposed to be checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the format that the session expects, which you could probably infer from:

```
select sysdate from dual;
```

In any case, you can just use the ISO date format ...

```
execute check(date '2011-06-06')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the default format.
You can specify it explicitly:

```
execute check(TO_DATE('2011/06/06', 'YYYY/MM/DD'));
```